# C++ - Windows - How to (write into && read from) command shell

Tags: c++, winapi, qt, logic

I want to execute a command in windows shell. And I want to receive the results. I tried to search the win32 console functions. But, I didn't see any character returning functions. can anybody help me out? I am doing it in Qt . So there is no problem if the solution is in Qt.

Note: Is there any way to write into the port like linux?

**EDIT:**
   Is it possible to use QProcess in this case?

Comment: The title says "how to write", but the body of the question says "I wand to receive the results". Do you want to read from or write to the spawned process?

Comment: @Eric I need both. I edited the question

Answer (score 2):

You should create another process, executing cmd, and get access to its stdin-stdout through pipes.
look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for example

Comment: Can you give me a stub for that

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=VS.85%29.aspx  - this is exactly what you need - here stdin and stdout being redirected. My previous example just calls CreateProcess...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for piped run. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Code from MSDN for parent process:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;

void CreateChildProcess(void); 
void WriteToPipe(void); 
void ReadFromPipe(void); 
void ErrorExit(PTSTR); 

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[]) 
{ 
   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr; 

   printf("\n->Start of parent execution.\n");

// Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

   saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
   saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
   saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

// Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 

   if ( ! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0) ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe")); 

// Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation")); 

// Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 

   if (! CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0)) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe")); 

// Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 

   if ( ! SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) )
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation")); 

// Create the child process. 

   CreateChildProcess();

// Get a handle to an input file for the parent. 
// This example assumes a plain text file and uses string output to verify data flow. 

   if (argc == 1) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("Please specify an input file.\n")); 

   g_hInputFile = CreateFile(
       argv[1], 
       GENERIC_READ, 
       0, 
       NULL, 
       OPEN_EXISTING, 
       FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY, 
       NULL); 

   if ( g_hInputFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateFile")); 

// Write to the pipe that is the standard input for a child process. 
// Data is written to the pipe's buffers, so it is not necessary to wait
// until the child process is running before writing data.

   WriteToPipe(); 
   printf( "\n->Contents of %s written to child STDIN pipe.\n", argv[1]);

// Read from pipe that is the standard output for child process. 

   printf( "\n->Contents of child process STDOUT:\n\n", argv[1]);
   ReadFromPipe(); 

   printf("\n->End of parent execution.\n");

// The remaining open handles are cleaned up when this process terminates. 
// To avoid resource leaks in a larger application, close handles explicitly. 

   return 0; 
} 

void CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{ 
   TCHAR szCmdline[]=TEXT("child");
   PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo; 
   STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE; 

// Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

   ZeroMemory( &piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );

// Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
// This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

   ZeroMemory( &siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
   siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 
   siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
   siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
   siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

// Create the child process. 

   bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL, 
      szCmdline,     // command line 
      NULL,          // process security attributes 
      NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
      TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
      0,             // creation flags 
      NULL,          // use parent's environment 
      NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
      &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
      &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 

   // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
   if ( ! bSuccess ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
   else 
   {
      // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
      // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
      // of the child process, for example. 

      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
      CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
   }
}

void WriteToPipe(void) 

// Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

   for (;;) 
   { 
      bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hInputFile, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
      if ( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

      bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
      if ( ! bSuccess ) break; 
   } 

// Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 

   if ( ! CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr) ) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle")); 
} 

void ReadFromPipe(void) 

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{ 
   DWORD dwRead, dwWritten; 
   CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE]; 
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
   HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

// Close the write end of the pipe before reading from the 
// read end of the pipe, to control child process execution.
// The pipe is assumed to have enough buffer space to hold the
// data the child process has already written to it.

   if (!CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr)) 
      ErrorExit(TEXT("StdOutWr CloseHandle")); 

   for (;;) 
   { 
      bSuccess = ReadFile( g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
      if( ! bSuccess || dwRead == 0 ) break; 

      bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf, 
                           dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
      if (! bSuccess ) break; 
   } 
} 

void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction) 

// Format a readable error message, display a message box, 
// and exit from the application.
{ 
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL );

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, 
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)+lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)+40)*sizeof(TCHAR)); 
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, 
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"), 
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf); 
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK); 

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use QProcess. It has 2 methods: readAllStandardOutput for stdout, and readAllStandardError for stderr. BUT you can't use startDetached.